# Show specific content on a page for each member when they log in

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I have two tables in my database. One is a list of members each, of course, having a different member ID. The second table is a list of items that have been designated to one member.

Please note that each table has a `user_id` column. Based on `user_id` I want only certain items displayed on their webpage.

When Joe logs to the members area, he is taken to a welcome page. On that welcome page I want Joe to be able to click on a link which will take him to a page. This page will show items that only Joe is allowed to see. If another member clicks on the link it shows a message that says something like Sorry, not for your eyes.

I really am only learning and have spent the past couple of days looking for help with this issue.

I am thinking, from what I have read, that I may just be able to amend the top of my "special page" with an if statement which would say something like

```
if user_id from table_members = user_id from table_items
Show all rows from table_items which = user_id
```

Comment: why to even show links that he is not allowed to see?

Comment: Joe is allowed to see the items in the table_items that have his user_id attached to them. Sue is allowed to see the items in the table_items if her user_id is attached to those items. But Joe is not allowed to see Sue's items and vice versa.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: `"select * from table_items where user_id=".user_id` replace execute that query you will only get rows whose user_id column value equals to user_id variable value.

Comment: Thanks so much. While I was waiting for your reply I was wondering if a select would work. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are huge number of tutorials available on internet on displaying dynamic data. Just try doing a search on "making dynamic webpages using php" like that.
let `$user_id` be a variable storing userid taken from user logged into the website.

`$query="select * from table_items where user_id=".$user_id ;`
   `$result=mysql_query($result);`

To fetch a row:

```
`$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);`
```

To fetch specific column from that row:

`$column_data=$row[$columnNameString];`

Execute that query you will only get rows whose user_id column value equals to user_id variable value.